# CRUD in JPA many to one bidirectional relationship

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, crud, bidirectional

I need to create a many-to-one relationship and I do not know if I'm doing it correctly because I cant do update and delete correctly. I'm using Spring boot and JPA repository in Java, the database is mysql.

I have a Post with a name, every Post can have several Comments, but I need use all together, if I want to add a comment, I sent the post with the new comment, for example:

```
{
    "name":"PostName",
    "comment: [
        {
            "text":"comment 1"
        },
        {
            "text":"comment 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

### Post.java

```
@Entity
public class Post {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Post")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy = "post")
    private List<Comments> Comments = new ArrayList<>();


    // Get and Set

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

### Comments.java

```
@Entity
public class Comments {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String text;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "post_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Post post;


    // Get and Set

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

### PostRepository.java

```
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {

    Club findByName(@Param("name") String name);

}
```

### Controller.java

```
@Autowired
PostRepository postRepository;

@RequestMapping(value="/posts", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<?> getPost(Pageable pageable){
    try {
        Page<Post> posts = postRepository.findAll(pageable);    
        return new ResponseEntity<>(posts,HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
    }
}


@RequestMapping(value="/newPost", method=RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<?> newPost(@RequestBody Post post){

    try {


        for (Comments comments: post.getComments()){
            comments.setPost(post);
        }


        postRepository.save(post);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
    }
}
```

I don't know if my work is right and I need update and delete methods.

Comment: And what is the problem you are having?

Comment: I don't know if my work is right and I need update and delete methods

Comment: Did you try it? Does it work? If not what is the problem / exception you are getting?

Comment: yes, it work, but I don't know if it's efficient and I want do a update method

Comment: I suggest you do some research and find some JPA tutorials about how to insert and update entities. If something does not work as expected, or you get some exception that you can't understand then come back and ask more specifically about that problem.

Comment: I dont find any tutorial with update one-to-many bidirectional relationship. This is my problem.

Comment: A 2 seconds Google search would have brought up this article. Which also happens to be exactly the example you are trying to build! Evidently you didn't even bother to do some research and understand the concepts. https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/